# Can I specify default conditions in Doctrine queries?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a basic Doctrine page entity defined.

```
namespace Example\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $status;
}
```

The $status attribute will be one of 'published', 'draft', 'deleted', 'pending'.

I'm wondering if it's possible for all queries on this entity to automatically include the condition `WHERE status = 'published'` unless the query specifies otherwise.

90% of the queries on this entity will be for published posts, and it will be far too easy for developers to inadvertently grab all draft, pending and deleted posts without realising they should be limiting results.

As far as I can tell, Doctrine's event listeners only apply to data manipulation and not selection.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible, the easier solution could be add a custom repository for the entity

```
namespace Example\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Example\Entity\PageRepository")
 */
class Page
```

Then you can create new methods, for example:

```
class PageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllPage()
        {
            return $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM Example\Entity\Page p WHERE u.status = "published"')->getResult();
        }
}
```

Or you can overriding  the defaults methods of the repository and add you where condition.

**documentation:** http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

Answer (score 1):

I recently have faced such task and solved it like this (but I don't think this is a symfony way:) ):
created a class that extends EntityREpository:

```
class MainPageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    protected function createQuery()
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $query = $queryBuilder
            ->select(array('p'))
            ->from('STMainSiteWebBundle:Page', 'p')
            ->where('p.deleted = :deleted')
            ->setParameter('deleted', false);

        return $query;
    }
}
```

and extended it whenever need to create a query:

```
class PageRepository extends MainPageRepository
{
    public function fetchAllByType($type, $offset = 0, $limit = 15)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query
            ->andWhere('p.pageType = :pageType')
            ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('pageType', $type)
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        $query->setFirstResult($offset);
        $query->setMaxResults($limit);

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize traits:

```
trait WithStatus
{
    public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = NULL)
    {
        $qb = parent::createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy);
        $qb->where("$alias.status = :status");
        $qb->setParameter('status', 'published');
        return $qb;
    }
}

class PageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    use WithStatus;
}
```

Comment: I like this, but the problem is, that the where will be overwrite by a new where outside.